# how to get previous control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

**how to get previous control in c#**

there is a method to `GetNextControl`
but there is no method to get previous control 
can any body tell me how could i get this

thanx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GetNextControl(Control control, bool forward)` you can specify if you want to get the control forward or backward. For instance to get the backward control of `button1`, you can do:

```
Control previous = GetNextControl(button1, false);//false indicates backward
```

Comment: @Haider you are welcome, don't forget to mark this answer as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question right.

Answer (score 3):

[GetNextControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol.aspx) will return the previous control if you pass `false` in its second argument:

```
Control prev = yourControl.GetNextControl(origin, false);
```

I agree the method name is somewhat confusing, but you're arguably indeed looking for the next control, only in the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it like:

```
var control = GetNextControl(origControl, false);
```