# How to impliment Back button Functionality in Windows Application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have few buttons in my user control page, Suppose I have btn A,B,C,D,E  with a back button, user click on button A then user click on B then user click on Back button, then page should navigate to button A. how can i achieve this?

Basically I wan't browser like back functionality in my windows application?

Comment: unfortunately this is not a code generator, please post the code showing what you`ve tried and let us know when you stumbled into something that you cant understand so we can help you, my most sincere regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882614/how-to-get-previous-control-in-c-sharp duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MDI form you can implement following methods...

```
Private Sub cmdBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdBack.Click
        Try
            Dim PrevForm As Form = Nothing
            For Each ChildForm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
                If ChildForm.Equals(Me.ActiveMdiChild) Then
                    If Not IsNothing(PrevForm) Then
                        Me.ActivateMdiChild(PrevForm)
                        PrevForm.Focus()
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
                PrevForm = ChildForm
            Next
            PrevForm = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub cmdForward_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdForward.Click
    Try
        Dim NextForm As Form = Nothing
        For Each ChildForm As Form In Me.MdiChildren.Reverse
            If ChildForm.Equals(Me.ActiveMdiChild) Then
                If Not IsNothing(NextForm) Then
                    Me.ActivateMdiChild(NextForm)
                    NextForm.Focus()
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            NextForm = ChildForm
        Next
        NextForm = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

To do the same...this will allow you to do exact what you want provided you following MDI child form hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You may solve it like this:

You have to make every `Click` handler a distinct method (no lambdas) which right before the end puts itself inside the `Tag` of the "Back" button. You may then `Invoke` it as needed.

Pseudo-coded example (just a proof-of-concept !)

```
void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Action A
    BackButton.Tag = ButtonAClicked;
}

void ButtonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Action B
    BackButton.Tag = ButtonBClicked;
}

void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((Button)sender).Tag !=null
        this.Invoke(ButtonB.Tag);
}
```

You don't really have to use the `.Tag`, you can store it in a `delegate` object too (for added decoupling).